# How to stack TextView's on same line with EditText's (stack a couple of rows)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

So I'm trying to stack some rows of TextView's and EditText's (one each on the same line) in a LinearLayout. But I manage to do it just with the first pair of the TextView and EditText. I just don't know how to go down to the next line.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.mylifeinformationsharedsocial.SignUpActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/username_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="start"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username_edit_text_id"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint_texts"
        android:gravity="end"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password_id"
        android:text="@string/password_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edit_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/passworde_hint_texts"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email_id"
        android:text="@string/email_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_edit_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint_text"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_button_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_button_text" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Picture:

[image]

You can see i can't see the other TextView's and EditText's, so how do i go down a line so that the password fields are on the 2nd line, the email fields on the 3rd and the button on the 4th line?

Comment: Remove the LinearLayout and just use the outer RelativeLayout. It has attributes for aligning childs and choosing relative positions (e.g. "below"). Your LinearLayout is horizontal so you can't go down.

Comment: @mvai Well i first used just a RelativeLayout with all the layout_blow and alignToRight but the Views werent on the same line. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012587/textviews-and-edidtexts-not-align-as-expected Heres the question i asked about it with the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in the comment to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012587/textviews-and-edidtexts-not-align-as-expected) that you want to use a `LinearLayout`. If so, you can **wrap several `horizontal` linear layouts in a `vertical` linear layout**, like so:

(see below for a `TableLayout`-based solution)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      >
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/username_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="start"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username_edit_text_id"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint_texts"
        android:gravity="end"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password_id"
        android:text="@string/password_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edit_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/passworde_hint_texts"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email_id"
        android:text="@string/email_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_edit_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint_text"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_button_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_button_text" 
        />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you wanted to use a `TableLayout` instead (probably faster rendering *and* the fields are aligned), use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
  <TableRow>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/username_text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="start"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/username_edit_text_id"
            android:hint="@string/username_hint_texts"
            android:gravity="end"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/password_id"
            android:text="@string/password_text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_edit_text_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="@string/passworde_hint_texts"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
       <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/email_id"
            android:text="@string/email_text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_edit_text_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint_text"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_button_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_button_text" 
            />
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

Comment: You're welcome. :-) If you want to align the fields, see the edit which shows how to do a TableLayout.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly do this with nested `LinearLayout` (one with vertical orientation which has a lot of `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation). But nested `ViewGroup` are discouraged in Android (it slows the UI).

You could perhaps use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html), [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) or [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Comment: Good proposal. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32024728/1587329 includes a TableLayout solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.example.mylifeinformationsharedsocial.SignUpActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/username_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="start"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username_edit_text_id"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint_texts"
        android:gravity="end"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password_id"
        android:text="@string/password_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edit_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/passworde_hint_texts"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email_id"
        android:text="@string/email_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_edit_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint_text"
        />
</LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_button_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_button_text" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using only one LinearLayout, that produces that all the textviews and EditTexts are drawing in only one line.

Instead of using a RelativeLayout (Please, for only put One view or One View group NOT use RelativeLayot,is quite inneficient, use FrameLayout instead) use something like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/username_text"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="start"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username_edit_text_id"
    android:hint="@string/username_hint_texts"
    android:gravity="end"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/password_id"
    android:text="@string/password_text"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password_edit_text_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="@string/passworde_hint_texts"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email_id"
        android:text="@string/email_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_edit_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint_text"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_up_button_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sign_up_button_text" 
    />
```